# Modifying collection of object string attributes using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, collections

I have a collection of Item objects.  Each item has a description.  I want to iterate through the collection, and for each description attribute, I want to replace the word "deliver" to "send".  The word "deliver" appears in each description.  For ex:

- item 1: We will deliver within 3 days.
- item 2: We will deliver within 2 days.
- item 3: We will deliver within 7 days.
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple search and replace, it sounds like you want something like this:

```
collection.each { |item| item.description.gsub!('deliver', 'send') }
```

If these are ActiveRecord objects or some such, you may also need an `item.save` in there.

If you need more powerful pattern matching,`String#sub` and related methods can accept a regex instead of a string for the first argument, but it's probably faster and more readable to use a string if that's all you need.  For more details and other options, see the [API docs for String#sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001185).